# How to wait for particular function to complete for starting next function? Without using thread in C#

Tags: c#

I have two functions.

```
Function1(varName);
Function2();
```

called in same sequence.
Here String `varName` is assigned by another function call which is in thread.

But here I want Funtion2 to complete before another value is assigned to varName (Funtion1 is called).

regards,
Sagy

example:

```
private void MainFuntion()
{
   Thread StartReadThread = new Thread(
            new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartRead));
   StartReadThread .Start(obj_ListDictionary); //ListDictionary object 
}

private void StartRead(object threadData)**
{
  ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4);
  m_Events = new ManualResetEvent[m_objSelNsfDataTable.Rows.Count];
  foreach (DataRow objRow in m_objSelNsfDataTable.Rows)
  {
    m_objThreadData                 =   new ThreadData();
    m_objThreadData.FilePath         =   objRow[0].ToString();

    m_objThreadData.ThreadIndex      =   index;
    m_Events[index]                  =   new ManualResetEvent(false);

    WaitCallback objWcb             =   new WaitCallback(FinalFunction);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(objWcb, m_objThreadData);

    index++; 
  }                               

  WaitHandle.WaitAll(m_Events); 
}

private void FinalFunction(object threadData)
{

  ThreadData threadData = (ThreadData)passedThreadData;
  String FilePath = threadData.FilePath;
  CopyContent(FilePath );                    
  OpenFolderForView();

}
```

Comment: Its not really that clear what you want?

Comment: Please clarify your question - it's not at all clear what's going on at the moment. If you could produce a short but complete example, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
string tempVarName = varName;
Function1(tempVarName);
Function2();
varName = tempVarName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://zvolkov.com/blog/post/2009/07/10/Better-ways-to-wait-for-queued-threads-to-complete.aspx) (explains how to do things like that in .NET 3.x and also 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

If Function1 calls the thread, you can use `thread.Join` before exits/return.